# How to convert RGB24 into BMP?

Tags: android, opengl-es, rgb, bmp

I am facing convertion problem in android

problem is unable to  convert RGB24 into BMP so that i  can use imageview to draw bmp.But BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray failed to decode . it returns null. I tried using OpenGL to render the rgb data but the problem is facing color related issue  instead of blue it is showing red color.

any idea?

Comment: For the color rendering, sounds like the data is really in BGR(A) and not RGB(A) -- OpenGL ES only supports RGBA core. Either fix the data or consider the EXT_bgra extension, if it is available.